# Generate Dates for particular range using SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to generate the dates for particular date range e.g. from 2010 to 2050
I googled but didn't find the solution. How I can I generate the date range using sql server. I need to do using sql query not to use stored procedure and block.
Any help will appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a numbers/tally table (a table with values from 0 to 10,000, let's say), call it dbo.Numbers, then select from there, calculating a date from each number, starting at 1 and up to whatever number you need:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, n.Number, '2010-01-01')
FROM dbo.Numbers AS n
WHERE n < [YourMaxNumberHere]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Recursive CTE to generate dates between specified period, but it's advisable to use [calendar](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=calendar%20table%20sql%20server&rlz=1C1GGRV_enIN752IN752&oq=calendar%20table%20sql%20server&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l4.3070j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=active) table which can be faster and less complex solution.

Demo with limited date range - http://rextester.com/XXUVO70452

```
Declare @StartDate as DATE = '2010-01-01'
       ,@EndDate   as DATE = '2050-12-31'

;WITH DateRange As
(
SELECT @StartDate as N
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, N)
FROM   DateRange 
WHERE  DATEADD(DAY, 1, N) < @EndDate
)       

SELECT * From DateRange OPTION (MAXRECURSION 15000);
```

Comment: 40 years is 14,310 days - I would expect a stack fault from that deep a recursion.

Comment: @Brian edited, made it 15000, I didn't test the solution with maxrecusion (0), wrote it, top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

Using numbers is better but you would need to create a DB object. You can also use a simple table variable and a WHILE loop

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(
 DateValue DATETIME
)

DECLARE @startDate DATETIME = '2010-01-01'
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME = '2050-01-01'

DECLARE @seqDays INT;
SELECT @seqDays = DATEDIFF(d, @startDate,@endDate)

DECLARE @val INT = 1
WHILE(@val <= @seqDays)
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(DATEADD(day, @val, @startDate))
 SET @val = @val + 1
END

SELECT * FROM @tbl
```

Or for the numbers table option described in another answer by @Dymeng, you can create your own table variable and join with that. You could have used SEQUENCE also but that will be over-do for a simpler thing.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(
  DateValue DATETIME
)

DECLARE @startDate DATETIME = '2010-01-01'
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME = '2050-01-01'

DECLARE @seqDays INT;
SELECT @seqDays = DATEDIFF(d, @startDate,@endDate)
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(
 DateInc INT IDENTITY(1,1)
)

DECLARE @val INT = 1
WHILE(@val <= @seqDays)
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO @tbl DEFAULT VALUES
 SET @val= @val + 1
END

SELECT DATEADD(day, a.DateValue, @startDate) FROM @tbl a
```

Answer (score 0):

With help some math, we can produce sufficient numbers for generate dates.

```
DECLARE @BeginDate DATETIME ='20100101'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME ='20500101'
DECLARE @Day INT = DATEDIFF( DAY, @BeginDate, @EndDate);
DECLARE @P INT = FLOOR( LOG( @Day, 2 ))

;WITH Base AS ( SELECT * FROM (VALUES(1),(2)) N (ID))
,Numbers AS (
     SELECT 1 I FROM Base 
     UNION ALL
     SELECT I+1 AS I FROM Base CROSS JOIN Numbers WHERE I < @P
)
, DateRange AS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order BY I), @BeginDate) DateValue FROM Numbers
)

SELECT * FROM DateRange WHERE DateValue < @EndDate
```